# Particle constrained to move in a sphere?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

> A particle of mass $m$ rests on the top of a smooth (frictionless) sphere of radius $R$. The particle is disturbed very slightly so that it starts to slide off the sphere, and its position can e described by the angle $\theta (t)$ betwwen the vertical and the line joining the centre of the sphere to the particle.
>
> Assume, for the moment, that the particle remains in contact with the sphere. What is the velocity of the particle as a function of $\theta$? What is the force between the particle and the sphere? At what value of $\theta$ does the particle leave the surface of the sphere?

Could someone provide a solution to this problem without using Lagrangian mechanics?

PS: Please do not worry I will copy your solution, my teacher asks me to do it in Lagrangian mechanics, which I did. But I wonder how can I solve this problem using Newtonian Mechanics. In particular, I feel a bit strange to think that the particle is confined to the sphere, since intuitively it will soon fall off.

Comment: Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please read [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"It will soon fall off" - indeed. Hence the part of the question that says

> "at what value of $\theta$ does the particle leave the surface"

By first seeing what force normal to the surface is needed to keep the particle "on the surface" and following the curvature, and then finding when this force is less than gravity, you break the problem into two easier chunks. It comes down to 1) "Here is an unreasonable assumption, what would happen", and 2) "When does the assumption break down (actually become unreasonable".

Makes it quite a quick way to solve. You can use conservation of energy to find the speed - and assuming a trajectory with bend radius $r$, and force of gravity holding the particle to the surface of $mg\cos\theta$, the result follows in a handful of lines.